# Error in URL Mapping in Spring MVC + Java Servlets

Tags: java, spring-mvc, servlets

In my sample Java/Spring-MVC/Webapp([github project](https://github.com/seshumadhav/bookflix-java)), When I try to open [http://localhost:8080/bookflix/querybook.html][2], I see a page.

1. Loading `http://localhost:8080/bookflix/querybook.html` happens smoothly
2. Hitting 'Search' button drives the browser to load `http://localhost:8080/bookflix/query` and leads to a 404.

I do not understand why GET/bookflix/query leads to a 404. Can anyone help me in fixing this. My github project is linked above. Code snippets below.

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>bookflix-java</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>querybook.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>bookflix</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>bookflix</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/bookflix/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**querybook.html**

```
<body>
<div id='container' class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <h2>Yet Another e-Bookshop</h2>
      <form method="get" action="query">
        Choose an author:<br /><br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="author" value="Tan Ah Teck" />Ah Teck
        <input type="checkbox" name="author" value="Mohammad Ali" />Ali
        <input type="checkbox" name="author" value="Kumar" />Kumar
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
      </form>
    </div>
  </div><!--/row-->
</div> <!-- /container -->
</body>
```

**bookflix-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.bookflix.controller" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean> 
</beans>
```

QueryController.java

```
... imports here ...
@Controller
public class QueryController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/bookflix/query", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public void helloWorld(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think you shouldn't be getting a 404? What part of your application should serve the request and why?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis My assumption is that , the method in QueryController:helloWorld() (with requestMapping: /bookflix/query) should receive the GET request for /bookflix/query. I also double checked by changing form action in querybook.html as /bookflix/query and the result is same. Pls correct if I was assuming wrongly.

Comment: I want you to go deeper. Why should that method receive the request?

Comment: as per web.xml, Any URL pattern like "bookflix/*" should be handled by bookflix-servlet.xml. This line(<context:component-scan base-package="com.bookflix.controller" />) in bookflix-servlet.xml would have made sure  QueryController.java(annotated with @Controller) is available to pick up "/bookflix/query, GET".

Comment: Component scanning only discovers and registers beans. It doesn't do anything else. It has no relation to the MVC stack.

Comment: I am confused. This is what I read: "When DispatcherServlet receives a web request, it determines which controllers should handle the incoming request. It first scans for all classes that are declared with the @Controller annotation.". My first hands-on with the app described in http://crunchify.com/simplest-spring-mvc-hello-world-example-tutorial-spring-model-view-controller-tips/ was working, and tried to mimic this new web app on same lines. May be I am missing some basics. If there is a more authoritative tutorial I should read up, pls suggest.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, Can you give some inputs?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, Can you please look into my response

Answer (score 0):

After some debugging I realized the issue. 
I was using an extraneous `/bookflix/` everywhere, which was leading into incorrect URL namespace. Removed that, and the application worked. 
This [github commit](https://github.com/seshumadhav/bookflix-java/commit/a179d40e68873a89e42cad63210406f778c83168)fixes the problem.

Thanks for helping.